# Turn off headless mode for Chromium binary @sparticuz/chromium

Tags: web-scraping, aws-lambda, chromium, playwright, aws-serverless

I'm using [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/) to scrape data and need to run in [AWS Lambda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AWS_Lambda). So I am using package *@sparticuz/chromium* for Chromium.

But for debugging, need to see browser in local, so how can we turn off headless mode? Is that even possible with it?

Comment: [The bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77764661/timeline) attracted a [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) plagiariser.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the headless/headful mode depending on the environment. Here we can check if the code is running on lambda or not.

```js
const isLambda = !!process.env.LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT;
console.log("Running on Lambda:", isLambda);
```

Now you can simply set headless to false when launching the browser.

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    args: chromium.args,
    defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
    executablePath: await chromium.executablePath(),
    headless: !isLambda, // <-- it will be false when running locally since the env is not present
});
```

Comment: setting headless: false is not working